# Showing form from async method and waiting on a result causes an extra blank form to appear

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

Okay, here goes.

I am building a C# Winforms application on top of the CefSharp Winforms minimum example.

I have moved all of the code out of the main form's constructor and into a new method called Initialize().  So I instantiate and then call Initialize.

```
var shellForm = new ShellForm();
shellForm.Initialize();
Application.Run(shellForm);
```

Initialize() is declared async void, because somewhere in the middle of it a form is displayed, from which user input is required before continuing.

```
//set up the form based on the number of projects and their names
ProjectSelect projectSelectForm = new ProjectSelect();
projectSelectForm.SetUpForm(projPaths); //show/hide buttons based on length of list
projectSelectForm.TopMost = true;
projectSelectForm.Show();
await projectSelectForm.WhenEventTriggered();
```

The task-waiting stuff is implemented in this class:

```
public static class ProjectSelectEventWaiter
{
    public static Task WhenEventTriggered(this ProjectSelect ps)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        ProjSelEvtHandler handler = null;
        handler = (selected) =>
        {
            tcs.TrySetResult(true);
            ps.ProjectSelected -= handler;
        };
        ps.ProjectSelected += handler;
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, except that when projectSelectForm is shown, another blank form appears above and to the left.  When I click close on this form, the VS debugger stops.  But if Initialize() is not declared async (and the await is removed), then this blank form doesn't appear.
[blank form appearing at top left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeMqY.png)

I guess there are several no-no's in all of the above.  I'm not a software engineer, I'm doing this project to demonstrate an important business case and there's no one else to do it.

The questions are: why might this form be appearing, and how could I try prevent it from appearing?

Comment: What is the idea behind `ShellForm`? How is that related to your `ProjectSelect` form?

Comment: I guess you are missing [tag:cefsharp] tag. I don't see where you show form, please refer to [mcve].

Comment: @JohnWu, ShellForm is the main form of the application, which is just a container/shell for a ChromiumWebBrowser.  I should have mentioned that.  Sinatr, yes there are holes in my post; I will try follow [mre] in future posts.  But JonasH has managed to guess what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely that the wrong form becomes the mainForm for the application. It seems like you intend `ShellForm` to be the main form for the application, but you are displaying another form before this has been fully initialized. This is usually not a good idea.

You probably want to fully create your main form before displaying any other form to solve the problem. This might require rewriting to do a multi-step initialization, first load the `shellform`, then ask for project, and finally do the final initialization of the `shellForm`.

Another workaround could be to create a hidden form as the main-form. That way you could display your ProjectSelection-form before the shell-form.

Comment: you were right about things being uninitialized - projectSelectForm was being shown even before InitializeComponent() was being called for ShellForm (which as you guessed is the main form).  So I will do some restructuring.